# How to serve a static file from an asp.net MVC area

Tags: asp.net-mvc-routing

I have a bunch of html files that sit in an Area of my asp.net MVC application. I can request them fine by giving the full path - including the sub-folder Areas - from the server. So for example, say I have an area called "**MyAreaName**" and a file called "**MyFile.html**" I can get it by going to:

```
http://mydomain/Areas/MyAreaName/MyFile.html
```

However, I need to request them without specifying the "Areas" part of the url as in:

```
http://mydomain/MyAreaName/MyFile.html
```

How can I accomplish this?

I think the reason I need to do this is irrelevant, but in case anyone is interested, the files in question are AngularJS templates, and AngularJS wants to access them relatively from it's application root. The AngularJS app is only small part of a bigger web application.

I know I can create a root level folder called "MyAreaName" and put the files in there, but this then splits my AngularJS app up, and I'd like it to remain in one place on the filesystem if possible.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it turns out I was wrong and the devil was in the detail.

In an AngularJS app, if the head section of the page has a  tag, all urls are relative to that.

I was able to set a base path for all templates by using ../../Areas/MyAreaName/ - which is relative to the  tag, then IIS took care of serving the static file for me because it was being requested directly.